# Is it possible to iterate through Tensor in graph mode?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api, data-augmentation, image-augmentation

I am trying to implement Aleju's [Imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) to [TFOD API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). Noticed that you can not iterate through Tensors in the graph mode . I looked up for the solution and tried many suggestions but neither of them worked for my case. Do you know any work around?

```
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa
from imgaug.augmentables.bbs import BoundingBox, BoundingBoxesOnImage
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import EagerTensor
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import numpy as np

augseq = iaa.Sequential([# augmentation options], random_order=True)

@tf.function
def augment(image, boxes):
    image_np = image.numpy().astype(np.uint8) if type(image) == EagerTensor else image
    boxes_np = boxes.numpy() if type(boxes) == EagerTensor else boxes
    width, height, _ = image_np.shape
    bbs = []
    for i in range(len(boxes_np)):
        box = boxes_np[i]
        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box.numpy()
        bbs.append(BoundingBox(
            x1=xmin*width, y1=ymin*height,
            x2=xmax*width, y2=ymax*height,))
    bbs = BoundingBoxesOnImage(bbs, shape=image_np.shape)
    image_aug, bbs_aug = augseq(image=image_np, bounding_boxes=bbs) # float np.ndarray
    bbs_aug = bbs_aug.remove_out_of_image().clip_out_of_image()
    
    boxes_aug = []
    for bb in bbs_aug:
        boxes_aug.append([bb.y1/height, bb.x1/width, bb.y2/height, bb.x2/width])
    boxes_aug = np.array(boxes_aug)
    
    return image_aug, boxes_aug
```

Stack Trace:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 112, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 558, in train_loop
    train_dataset_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 348, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1199, in experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function
    return self.distribute_datasets_from_function(dataset_fn, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1191, in distribute_datasets_from_function
    dataset_fn, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py", line 979, in _distribute_datasets_from_function
    options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 181, in get_distributed_datasets_from_function
    build=build,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 1618, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 1639, in build
    self._input_contexts, self._input_workers, self._dataset_fn))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/input_lib.py", line 2350, in _create_datasets_from_function_with_input_context
    dataset = dataset_fn(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 553, in train_dataset_fn
    input_context=input_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py", line 906, in train_input
    reduce_to_frame_fn=reduce_to_frame_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 258, in build
    batch_size, input_reader_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 237, in dataset_map_fn
    fn_to_map, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 348, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3886, in map_with_legacy_function
    use_legacy_function=True))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 5505, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4540, in __init__
    self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 544, in add_to_graph
    self._create_definition_if_needed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 380, in _create_definition_if_needed
    self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 407, in _create_definition_if_needed_impl
    capture_resource_var_by_value=self._capture_resource_var_by_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 970, in func_graph_from_py_func
    outputs = func(*func_graph.inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4458, in wrapped_fn
    ret = wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4440, in wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(self._func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 699, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py", line 886, in transform_and_pad_input_data_fn  *
        tensor_dict = pad_input_data_to_static_shapes(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py", line 272, in transform_input_data  *
        out_tensor_dict = data_augmentation_fn(out_tensor_dict)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/inputs.py", line 623, in augment_input_data  *
        tensor_dict = preprocessor.preprocess(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py", line 4812, in preprocess  *
        results = func(*args, **params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py", line 4422, in _adjust_imgaug  *
        adjusted_image, adjusted_boxes = tf.cast(imgaug_utils.augment(image,boxes), tf.float32)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/core/imgaug_utils.py", line 24, in augment  *
        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box.numpy()

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Here is what I tried and did not work:

1. Enable eager execution(It is default in tf 2.x)
2. Decorate/Not Decorate function with @tf.function.
3. Create Tf session and try to eval() or run():

- *InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'while/Placeholder' with dtype int32*

4. Tried on both TPU and CPU

Comment: Try `tf.while_loop`

Answer (score 0):

Now there exists tf.range()

A brief example

```
# here is a 3d tensor. 
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]]))

#Now loop over its largest parts

length = x.shape[0]
for n in tf.range(length):
    do_some_naugty_things(x[n])
```